# AWS DynamoDB count query results without retrieving

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I would like to check how many entries are in a DynamoDB table that matches a query *without retrieving the actual entries*, using boto3.

I want to run a machine learning job on data from DynamoDB table. The data I'm training on is a data that answers a query, **not the entire table**. I want to run the job only if I have enough data to train on.
Therefore, I want to check if I want to check that I have enough entries that match the query.
It is worth mentioning that the DynamoDB table I'm querying is *really big*, therefore actual retrieving is no option unless I actually want to run the job.

I know that I can use `boto3.dynamodb.describe_table()` to get how many entries there are in the *entire table*, but as I mentioned earlier, I want to know only how many entries match a query.

Any ideas?

Comment: [boto3.query()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.query)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was asked and answered in the past, see  [How to get item count from DynamoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316643/how-to-get-item-count-from-dynamodb)

Basically, you need to use the "Select" parameter to tell DynamoDB to only count the query's results, instead of retrieving them.

As usual in DynamoDB, this is truncated by paging: if the result set (not the count - the actual full results) is larger than 1 MB, then only the first 1 MB is retrieved, and the items in it counted, and you get back this partial count. If you're only interested in checking whether you have "enough" results - this may even be better for you - because you don't want to pay for reading a gigabyte of data just to check if the data is there. You can even ask for a smaller page, to read less - depending on what you consider enough data.

Just remember that you'll pay Amazon not by the amount of data **returned** (just one integer, the count) but by the amount of data **read from disk**. Using such counts excessively may lead to surprising large costs.