# Using Lambda with Nodejs Count Some queries in Dynamo DB

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework, aws-sdk-nodejs

After using the below to pull data from Dynamo db sucessfully

```
async function pullone(sessionid) {
  const params = {
    TableName: dynamodbTableName,
    Key: {
      'sessionid': sessionid
    }
  };
  return await dynamodb.get(params).promise().then((response) => {
    return response.Item
  }, (error) => {
    console.error('Do your custom error handling here. I am just gonna log it: ', error);
  });
}
```

Instead of 'return response.Item' i just want to return the count instead.

I tried doing count(pullone(sessionid)) but not sure if that is even a valid method. Please assist

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27316643/how-to-get-item-count-from-dynamodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your question, but:

Since you're requesting data associated with a primary key, you'll get either 0 or 1 element in `Item`.

So, if you aim to know if "you've found something or not", you can use `Number(response.Item != null)` and you'll get 1 in case of "something" and 0 in case of "nothing".

If, instead, your data contains a "count" attribute, then `(await pullone(sessionId)).count` should work.

Otherwise, you have to query your DB (but you'll get `Items` (plural) in your response) and use the `length()` function of the `Items` array you'll get in the response.

Comment: the idea works. i.e one should just test for null. Thanks